# How to make a share text content in android which has a default text

Tags: android

Hi I want to share a default content plus the text the user wants to share:

```
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, " - You're using App v. 10.2");
    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
    startActivity(sendIntent);
```

What I want is like this: 
USER TEXT HERE 
- You're using App v. 10.2

How can I do this? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check with this code. it works good.

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("*/*");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Body text of the new status");    
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share image using"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent .setType("text/html");
sendIntent .putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml("<p>USER TEXT HERE.</p> <br \> <p>- You're using App v. 10.2</p>"));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent ,"Share using"));
```

Comment: when I tried ur code, facebook and other social networks are not in the list. Why is it like that?